# Opened option list of a mat-select within a mat-dialog is not closing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-select within mat-dialog. I open mat-select-options by clicking on it. Now if I try close mat-select-options by clicking anywhere within mat-dialog it not closing.

Comment: if you can create a stackblitz, it will be easier to help you

Comment: i found this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-bbsbdh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding close button in option.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" #foodSelect>
    <button style="float:right" type="button" mat-icon-button (click)="foodSelect.close()">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I am using angular 10 and running into this same issue, where the mat select drop down wont close if i click anywhere in the mat dialog. If I click outside the dialog it will close. Have you come across any other solution beyond the button example above?

Comment: Thanks, life saver partner

Comment: @nabeelh21 found a solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Make sure the class `cdk-global-overlay-wrapper` has the same z-index as `cdk-overlay-backdrop` and `cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box`.
In my case we set the overlay wrapper's z-index to be 99999 but didn't adjust the other two. Easiest fix is to not mess with materials z-index's :)